# How to automate saving plots with Shell scripting

Tags: bash, shell

I have 10 `.txt` files that contain my data as in `output1.txt`, `output2.txt`, `output3.txt` and so on. I plot this data with the following commands:

```
#!/bin/bash
gnuplot
set o "output1.png"
p "output1.txt" u 1:2 with lines
set o "output2.png"
p "output2.txt" u 1:2 with lines
set o "output3.png"
p "output3.txt" u 1:2 with lines
```

and so on.

Obviously when I have like 100 data files, this approach is not very useful. How can I write a shell script that basically automates saving my data into files with a `for` loop in a script? Is it even possible or should I turn somewhere else like a python script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you require something like this:

```
for each in output*.txt
do
  BASE_NAME=$(basename $each .txt)
  echo ${BASE_NAME}
  gnuplot <<- EOF
    set o "${BASE_NAME}.png"
    p "$each" u 1:2 with lines
  EOF
done
```

Comment: It gives the following error:
         cell2.sh: line 6: BASE_NAME: command not found
                   line 0: warning: Skipping unreadable file "output*.txt"
                   line 0: No data in plot

Comment: Is there files outputX.txt in the current folder?

Comment: Yes, it plots constantly but it doesn't save the data

Comment: It still gives this error: cell2.sh: line 7: output: command not found
cell2.sh: line 7: BASE_NAME: command not found

Answer (score 0):

Completely untested:

```
#!/bin/bash

for fn in $(ls output*.txt); do
    # Extract file "ID"
    fid=${fn:6:(-4)}
    # Build output png
    out=output${fid}.png
    # Echo the commands
    echo set o "${out}"
    echo p "${fn}" u 1:2 with lines
done
```

Which you'd either pipe directly into gnuplot:

```
./abovescript.sh | gnuplot
```

Or redirect into a script file, then call using gnuplot

```
./abovescript.sh > myscript
gnuplot myscript
```

Updated per Mark Setchell's suggestions:

```
for fn in output*.txt; do
    # Extract the file "base"
    fid=${fn%%.txt}
    # Build output png
    out=${fid}.png
    # Echo the commands
    echo set o \"${out}\"
    echo p \"${fn}\" u 1:2 with lines
done | gnuplot
```

This also assumes that your "input" files are named exactly `outputX.txt` where `X` doesn't contain any whitespace.

Added by Mark Setchell... just for fun, the plots look kind of more professional if you label them a little bit, by adding the following:

```
...
out=...
# Echo the commands
echo set title \"${out} - plotted with gnuplot\"
echo set ylabel \"y axis\"
echo set xlabel \"x axis\"
```

Comment: A few suggestions... replace `$(ls..)` with `output*.txt` to avoid parsing the output of `ls`. Use `fid=${fn%%.txt}` to strip the extension. Add `| gnuplot` after `done`.

Comment: Oh, and add a backslash in front of every `"`

Comment: May I ask, what is the function of %% sign in fn%% from a syntax point of view?

Comment: This gives the following error: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `fid'
line 4: ` fid = ${fn%%.txt}'

Comment: `${string%%substring}` means delete the longest match of `substring` from the back of `string` -- see [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html).

Comment: `fid = ${fn%%.txt}'` should be `fid = ${fn%%.txt}` -- looks like you added an extra single quote at the end of that line.

Comment: Thank you but unfortunately it still doesn't work: set o ""
                 ^
         cannot open file; output not changed
         line 0: util.c: No such file or directory

--Basically it gives an error when gnuplot tries to create a new file

Comment: Are you running under bash? I mean is your first line `#!/bin/bash`? (You do need to be.)

Comment: You can also remove the `|gnuplot` at the end of the script and run it again and see what it is sending to `gnuplot`.

Comment: Yeah I added the #!/bin/bash, however it still doesn't seem to work for some reason. I also tried several other things to no avail at the moment.

Comment: Try running it again and then click `edit` under your question and paste your current code and the output so we can help...